# get the active fetchXML value of view from javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, fetchxml, webresource

I am doing ribbon button for a view, the button should run an operation on each record the user sees.

e.g. If the user applies the filters to show only records with condition **fieldX = valueX** so the operation will be set on these records only. (with no count limitation)

for this purpose I need to get the fetchXml settings of this view. but the current, not default, because the user could change them.

How can I do it from web resource javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ribbon Workbench to create the button on "Home". From there add a Command > Actions > JavaScript Action > Add Parameter > CRM Parameter > SelectedControlAllItemReferences

Now the JavaScript function you call will have an array of item references from the current list.

[Screenshot of the Ribbon Workbench menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goQFJ.png)